# How disable sourceCaption from primefaces picklist

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, caption, picklist

Does anyone knows how to disable the *sourceCaption* from primefaces picklist template?

I need that my user set three informations 
(*crudMB.upf.dataImplantacao*, *crudMB.upf.responsavelImplantacao*, *crudMB.upf.prazoSenha* ) before selecting any options at the picklist.

At my code you guys can see this three variables that i need to enable the source part of the picklist.

```
<p:panel header="Produtos Fornecidos" style="height: auto;">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Data Implantação:" />
        <p:calendar value="#{crudMB.upf.dataImplantacao}"  />

        <h:outputLabel value="Responsavel Implantação: " />
        <p:inputText value="#{crudMB.upf.responsavelImplantacao}" />

        <h:outputLabel value="Prazo de Senha: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{crudMB.upf.prazoSenha}" >
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione Um" itemValue="" itemDisabled="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{crudMB.prazosSenha}" var="ps" itemLabel="#{ps.descricao}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:pickList id="picklist"  value="#{crudMB.produtosFornecidos}" var="pf" itemValue="#{pf}" itemLabel="#{pf.nome}" converter="genericPickListConverter" >
        <f:facet name="sourceCaption" >Disponiveis</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="targetCaption" >Escolhidos</f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{crudMB.onTransfer}" />

            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{pf.nome}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{pf.plataforma}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{pf.versaoAtual}"/>
            </p:column>

        </p:pickList>

    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: what do you mean by  'disable source caption'? Do you want the picklist to be in a kind of 'disabled' modus?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want. But only the part where the user select the  avaliable options.

Comment: And the buttons then to prevent removing things as wel? It is not possible out of the box and you can most likely only hack something in client-side by manipulating the javascript. No other ideas sorry